# Sqlite Update Query not working | Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I am new to Android apps and trying to run Sqlite-query like this;

```
String query = "Select IsEnabled from Translation_Language ORDER BY TransLation_Language_ID";
Cursor Translations = SplashScreen.database.rawQuery(query,null);
```

and it is working. But i don't know how to update the same table. I have tried some methods but failed. Could anyone help me to resolve it???

**Update query code**

```
SplashScreen.database.update("Translation_Language", "IsEnabled", "TransLation_Language_ID", new String[] {"1", "8"});
```

I  want to set IsEnabled property to 1 that have ID=8.

Comment: try this `db.update("Translation_Language", "IsEnabled","TransLation_Language_ID" + "='" + ID + "'", new String[] {"1", "8"});`

Comment: its showing syntax error "The method update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String[])"   @SimplePlan

Comment: then try this                 `ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("IsEnabled","1");     db.update("Translation_Language", cv, "TransLation_Language_ID=?", new String[] { "8" });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

```
 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
 cv.put("IsEnabled","1");  
 db.update("Translation_Language", cv, "TransLation_Language_ID=?", new String[] { "8" });
```